# How can I code the slid down content to slideup when mouse is off the trigger and slid down content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, slide

I've gotten the webdsn-drop to slide up when the mouse is off of this div but it still stays up when the mouse is off the#web button. How can I make the div disappear when the mouse is off both the #web button and the #webdsn-drop

Thank you for all help!

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
        <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
        <a id="pf" href="posters+flyers.html">Posters & Flyers</a>
        <a id="web" href="#">Website Design</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="webdsn-drop">
        <div id="border">
        <h1>WEBSITE DESIGN</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="pfdsn-drop">
        <div id="border">
        <h1>POSTERS & FLYERS</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

}

#nav-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 745px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#nav-container h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;

}

#nav-container a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "calibri light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

}

#nav-container a:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-container a:active {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

#nav-container h1:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

/*-----------WEB-DESIGN-DROP---------*/

#border{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#border h1{
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


#webdsn-drop{
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
    font-family: 'calibri light';
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#web').hover(function() {
  $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $('#webdsn-drop').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
    });
});



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

I added the line **$('#web').Hover()** In order that there would be no repeated opening with multiple hover

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#web').hover(function () {
                if ($('#webdsn-drop').is(":hidden")) {
                    $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown();
                }
            }, function () {

                    $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
            });
```

Comment: I tried this but the slide down content doesnt stay when the moise moves onto it, it has helped the nav button part but i want the slid down content to stay slid down until the mouse moves off that too

Answer (score 1):

I sat for a long time and thought about how to implement it, while it turned out so crookedly, but I'm completely sure that there is a better implementation

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            let StatusHower = false;

            $('#web').hover(function () {
                if ($('#webdsn-drop').is(":hidden")) {
                    $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown();
                }
            }, function () {

                StatusHower = true;

                $('#webdsn-drop').hover(function () {
                    StatusHower = false;
                }, function () {
                    $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
                    });


                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (StatusHower) {
                        $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
                        StatusHower = !StatusHower;
                    }
                },100)

                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to add a mouseleave listener when the event has already been fired.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#web').hover(function() {
    $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: The code provided do work but the slid down content doesnt stay after mouse moves onto the slid down content